# Neat iframe scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, scroll

For a web page, practical reasons demand an iframe to link to other content within the domain. However, while the rest of the page (outside the iframe) doesn't need to scroll, the content within the iframe does. Rather than having a scroll bar within the iframe, how could I use the scroll bar of the page to scroll within the iframe?

The iframe links to a page from the same domain, and while it may not be possible to do this without scripting, ideally it would be a CSS-only solution. If necessary, javascript can be used.

If it helps, the iframe runs up the the bottom edge of the page, so I have been playing around with ways to extend it past the bottom and do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to have the iFrame resize to the contained content to do this. A task that is after all these years still not as simple as it should be. Take a look at this lib that does the hard work for you.

**https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer**